# Angular 2 Release (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for ElementRef: (?)

Tags: angular

I just upgraded to the Angular 2 Final Release from RC 4 and I am getting the error: `(SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for ElementRef: (?)`

This is my app.module.ts code:

```
import { NgModule, ElementRef }       from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {DashboardModule} from '../../areas/dashboard/dashboard.module';
import {AppComponent} from '../../areas/dashboard/app.component';
import { NgGridModule } from 'angular2-grid';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, DashboardModule, NgGridModule],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [ElementRef]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I can't just import it tat the component level because I am also using plugins that rely on it (for instance [angular2-grid](https://github.com/BTMorton/angular2-grid))

any ideas?

thank you in advance

EDIT:

Here is some code with a call to ngGrid in it:

```
<div [attr.ngGrid]="gridConfig" (onItemChange)="onGridItemChange($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let Widget of Widgets" class="gridWidget" [class.showingGridView]="Widget.gridview.show" [(attr.ngGridItem)]="Widget.widget" id="widget_{{Widget.id}}">
            <div class="title handle"></div>
            <h5 class="grid-item-title">{{Widget.title}}</h5>
            <a *ngIf="Widget.gridview.show && (Widget.chart.data || Widget.chart.datasets)" class="backLink" title="Back to Chart" (click)="toggleGridView($event)" href="" id="{{Widget.id}}"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
            <a (click)="removeWidgetFromBoard($event)" href="" class="removeLink" id="removeWidgetLink_{{Widget.id}}" title="Remove Widget from Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            <base-chart *ngIf="!Widget.gridview.show" class="chart" id="chart_{{Widget.id}}"
                        [attr.data]="Widget.chart.data"
                        [attr.datasets]="Widget.chart.datasets"
                        [attr.labels]="Widget.chart.labels"
                        [attr.options]="Widget.chart.options"
                        [attr.legend]="Widget.chart.legend"
                        [attr.chartType]="Widget.chart.chartType"
                        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
            <iwe-datatable *ngIf="Widget.gridview.show" id="data-table"
                           attr.table_title="{{Widget.title}}"
                           attr.table_summary="A table with data for {{Widget.title}}."
                           attr.border_type="vertical"
                           attr.table_content="{{Widget.gridview.tableData}}">
            </iwe-datatable>
            <img class="smallSpinner" [ngClass]="{visible: Widget.showSpinner}" src="/iwe/img/BG_Spinner_32.gif" alt="Small Spinner" width="34" height="34">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you pass `ElementRef` as provider in your module?

Comment: I started passing it there because, if I do not, I get an error saying "no provider for elementref"

Comment: Where are you using `ElementRef`?

Comment: I am not in my code - I removed every instance of it to try and circumvent the error, but it's being used by plugins I am using, such as the angular2-grid I mentioned above, I found references to it in a solution wide search. Their files have an "import" statement but it still throws an error that no provider was found if I do not reference it in my module

Comment: Could you add some code where you use `angular2-grid`?

Comment: I wonder why agGrid need it? Its a plugin and reference of ElementRef  has to be there in plugin.

Comment: @yurzui added above

Comment: I have faced same issue i could resolve by removing reference. I had declared constructor and parameter which was not used and the same class has injected in app.module.ts so just by removing constructor and parameter as i am not using that now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide `ElementRef` yourself. `ElementRef` is provided by DI dynamically and it's always the reference to the host element of the component where it is injected.

Comment: But if I dont provide ElementRef myself, it throws an error saying there is no provider for ElementRef

Comment: Then you're injecting it somewhere where it is not supposed to be injected. For example if you inject it to a global service, there is no way Angular DI can know what `ElementRef` you want it to inject.

Comment: The only place I am injected it is in my app.module.ts (above). If i remove it from there, it says `no provider for...`

Comment: In `app.module.ts` you are providing it. The code in your question doesn't show where you are injecting it (constructor parameter). Are you actually injecting it somewhere in your application?

Comment: I am not, I got rid of all instances of it in my code to try and just get the application to run. The only place it is being called is in the plugins. My code doesn't have any references to it at all anymore

Comment: Hard to tell. Providing it explicitly definitely won't solve your problem.

Comment: Tried using ElementRef within a resolve and get `there is no provider for ElementRef`

Comment: @fidev I guess you're doing this in a service. `ElementRef` can only be injected to directives and components.

Answer (score 0):

Try delete `node_modules` and `typings` directories and run `npm i`.

People run into all kind of strange errors / issues after upgrade, and a clean npm install seems to fix a lot of times.

If that still doesn't work, post your `package.json`.